# Is there a MATLAB version of partial Schur decomposition?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I'm quite surprised not to find one in standard library. Is there some reason it is missing or I just need to use a specific toolbox?

Implementing it myself would be very problematic because of the complexity of algorithm involved.

Comment: You mean other than the [`schur`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/schur.html) function? You want something akin to `eigs` that only decomposes part of the matrix corresponding to particular eigenvectors?

Comment: You can also look into Jacobi-Davidson methods. There is some ancient (and rather crusty-looking) Matlab code [here](http://www.math.uu.nl/~sleij101/JD_software/jd.html) that claims to return the partial Schur decomposition. I'm really not sure of the difference between Schur decomposition and partial Schur decomposition.

Comment: @horchler Exactly! I want schurs which behaves like eigs. Thank you for reference I will take a look at Jacobi-Davidson methods.

Comment: For more current stuff you might also investigate Arnoldi methods. See the [SLEPc](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/) project. The code is all C-based, but if you can compile it, they include a (sadly Python-like) Matlab interface to the library. [This PDF](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/documentation/reports/str4.pdf) in their documentation specifically discusses partial Schur decomposition.

Comment: You could also try the SciComp StackExchange site